# Accessing a non-tag element of an xml file

Tags: python, xml

I am new to python xml parsing.
I am parsing an xml file using elementtree concept.

I went through the domumentation and i have written a script in python.

```
doc = parse(filePath)

name = doc.getElementsByTagName('package')

print(name)
child_name = name[0]
print(child_name)
print(child_name.tag)
print(child_name.attrib)
```

The code works to an extent, but the output of child_name.tag and child_name.attrib does not work. When i execute i get his error:

```
AttributeError: 'Element' object has no attribute 'tag'
```

In the xml file for the elements the package has id, name, alias , comments desc and so on.
I need to access these stuffs.

Can anyone please tell me how i should approach this problem

Answer (score 0):

Both of these

```
print(child_name.tag)
print(child_name.attrib)
```

Will give an error.

To approach this use:

```
print(child_name['tag'])
print(child_name['attrib'])
```

However, when doing this method you need absolute assurance that the structure does not change.

One way is to use

```
try:
   print(child_name['tag'])
   print(child_name['attrib'])
catch:
   pass
```

Where `pass` is you should consider different indexes.

For this part you could:

```
for item in name:
   print(item)
```

Comment: Hi i tried to use the way that you have suggested. But still i am not able to go along with it. I did not get any output again, though i am still able to get some output like: `<DOM Element: package at 0x2d97170>`. But how to access these elements, is still something that i am trying to find out.

Comment: Try using this `the_page = xmltodict.parse(doc)` make sure to `import xmltodict`. Then you should be able to perform a dictionary access on the file. Otherwise try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834393/python-xml-file-open

Comment: I solved the problem, it was a simple one, i used `root.iter('package')` and i got the output i needed.