# counting the words in xml file results error

Tags: python, xml

I am new to python,I am trying to parse a xml document to count the total no. of words,I tried the below program to count the n no. of words in the file,But i get the error as follows:

After getting this error,i installed "utils",but still it comes.
Is there any other easy way of getting the totla no. of words of an xml document in python,Please help!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\xmlp.py", line 1, in <module>
    from xml.dom import utils,core
ImportError: cannot import name utils
```

Coding

```
from xml.dom import utils,core
import string
reader = utils.FileReader('Greeting.xml')

doc = reader.document

Storage = ""

for n in doc.documentElement.childNodes:
 if n.nodeType == core.TEXT_NODE:
  # Accumulate contents of text nodes
  Storage = Storage + n.nodeValue
print len(string.split(Storage))
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll find it easier to use `ElementTree`, eg:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

xml = '<a>one two three<b>four five<c>Six Seven</c></b></a>'
tree = ET.fromstring(xml)
total = sum(len(text.split()) for text in tree.itertext())
# 7
```

But use `tree = ET.parse('Greeting.xml')` to load your real data.

Comment: i tried ur code,my xml file is around 12 mb,but errors as `Traceback   File "C:\Python27\xmlp.py", line 3, in <module>
    tree = ET.parse('myxml.xml')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1182, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 656, in parse
    parser.feed(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1642, in feed
    self._raiseerror(v)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1506, in _raiseerror
    raise err
ParseError: undefined entity &ouml;: line 47, column 18
>>> `

Comment: @adsalila right... so it's not well formed XML then... Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237466/python-elementtree-support-for-parsing-unknown-xml-entities as to how to work around it if you need to

Comment: But,if i try ur code to a small xml file i get error as `File "C:\Python27\xmlp.py", line 4, in <module>
    total = sum(len(text.split()) for text in tree.itertext())
AttributeError: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'itertext'`

Answer (score 0):

imho you do not need utils and core
just `from xml.dom import minidom`

look a similar example here: [Python XML File Open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834393/python-xml-file-open?answertab=votes#tab-top)