# How to read a xml file in python as dictionary?

Tags: python, xml

There has been some answers like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55818101/how-to-read-xml-content-in-dictionary-from-a-xml-file-in-python), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106480/really-simple-way-to-deal-with-xml-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148119/how-to-convert-an-xml-string-to-a-dictionary), but they do not seem to work for me to open an `xml` file and get the contents as a simple and convenient python dict.

Here is what I tried:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def etree_to_dict(t):
    d = {t.tag: {} if t.attrib else None}
    children = list(t)
    if children:
        dd = defaultdict(list)
        for dc in map(etree_to_dict, children):
            for k, v in dc.items():
                dd[k].append(v)
        d = {t.tag: {k:v[0] if len(v) == 1 else v for k, v in dd.items()}}
    if t.attrib:
        d[t.tag].update(('@' + k, v) for k, v in t.attrib.items())
    if t.text:
        text = t.text.strip()
        if children or t.attrib:
            if text:
              d[t.tag]['#text'] = text
        else:
            d[t.tag] = text
    return d

with open('run.tcx', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

from pprint import pprint
pprint(etree_to_dict(data))
```

which resulted in a error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tester.py", line 33, in <module>
    pprint(etree_to_dict(data))
  File "tester.py", line 8, in etree_to_dict
    d = {t.tag: {} if t.attrib else None}
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tag'
```

I also tried with some other function from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148119/how-to-convert-an-xml-string-to-a-dictionary) answer:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

from copy import copy

    def dictify(r,root=True):
        if root:
            return {r.tag : dictify(r, False)}
        d=copy(r.attrib)
        if r.text:
            d["_text"]=r.text
        for x in r.findall("./*"):
            if x.tag not in d:
                d[x.tag]=[]
            d[x.tag].append(dictify(x,False))
        return d
```

and got the same error.
The file I am opening starts as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><TrainingCenterDatabase xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-i
nstance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabasev2.xsd"><Activities><Activity S
port="Running"><Id>2022-08-20T05:58:57Z</Id><Lap StartTime="2022-08-20T05:58:57Z"><Calories>1060.0</Calories><DistanceMeters>14468.162</DistanceMeters><TotalTimeSeconds>6259.
0</TotalTimeSeconds><Track><Trackpoint>...
```

and seems to be in xml format.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here?

Comment: Perhaps you can try xmltodict? https://pypi.org/project/xmltodict/.

Comment: The code seems incomplete. Are you actually parsing the XML? A function name such as `etree_to_dict` suggests that ElementTree is involved, but that is not the case.

Comment: How to create the text to am ElementTree? I tried `tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(data))` and when I use `tree` instead of `data` I get the same error

Comment: But `from xml.etree.ElementTree import XML, fromstring
tree = fromstring(data)` seems to be workig